# How to implement Panorama effect to my mobile application in PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, cordova, kendo-mobile

Is it possible to implement a Panoramic effect in a mobile application using PhoneGap? I have started my project for Windows Phone 8 and once it is ready, it will be published for other platforms as well.

I have an option to add a "Windows Phone Panorama Page" in my project, but will this work on other platforms after publishing?

Please let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!!!

Comment: I think you need to first understand that all the mobile platforms are different and have their own set of design guidelines.
A panorama page may be great for Windows but not for iOS/Android. So I feel you should have a separate view for each of the platforms.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I want the app to look same on all 3 major platforms, at least in terms of panoramic effect. So is it possible any how?